# Intel Rapid Start Technology automatically changes to manual startup in services

Tags: windows-7, intel-rapid-start

I just did a clean install of Windows on my laptop, and installed all the drivers including IRST (Intel Rapid Start Technology).

Whenever I restart my laptop or leave it running for a few minutes, IRST automatically stops, and when I look up IRST in services, I see the startup type set to manual.  But it was set to automatic when I installed it and restarted my system the first time.

I tried changing it to automatic and restarting my system, which seemed to work.  But again, when I leave my system running, it automatically changes to manual and stops running.  I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was meant to run automatically, it would be set to auto from the very beginning. It's on manual by default, so it shouldn't be changed to automatic.

You don't want services running pointlessly and consuming resources.